# Stancl/Tenancy: I want to auto seed when tenant is created

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

As the document said, [Tenancy config. dog](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v2/configuration/)
this flag `seed_after_migration` as `true`, but it doesnot seed any when tenant is created.

Answer (score 3):

Check in `App\Providers\TenancyServiceProvider` if the `Jobs\SeedDatabase::class` line is uncommented (at line 30).

If this doesn't solve the issue, try the following.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

The tenancyforlaravel package comes with the seed command. After running tenant migrations automatically when tenants are created, you have to run the tenants:seed command to run your seeders. Also you might want to turn on the --force key in the seeder_parameters array in the tenancy.php config file.

```
php artisan tenants:seed
```